# Unable to connect a Postgres Docker Container from my localhost (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, localhost

I'm reading about it and trying to solve it by myself:

[ECONNREFUSED for Postgres on nodeJS with dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357567/econnrefused-for-postgres-on-nodejs-with-dockers)

[Unable to connect to Postgres DB due to the authentication type 10 is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppor)

[Unable to connect to Docker Postgres from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210698/unable-to-connect-to-docker-postgres-from-outside)

I did a lot of steps and I don't achieve a connection from my python script to Postgres Docker:

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=project1

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=adminadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Then I run

```
docker-compose up
```

My script.py:

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="host.docker.internal",
    database="project1",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    port=5432
)

print(conn)

# create a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# execute a statement
print('PostgreSQL database version:')
result = cur.execute('SELECT version()')
print(result)
```

When I try to connect to DB, the console triggers multiple errors if I change host:

host.docker.internal (I think I have to do something in postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf, but I'm not sure):

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (192.168.1.145), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.145", user "root", database "project1", SSL off
```

localhost

```
 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

0.0.0.0

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address (0x00002741/10049)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

BTW: Docker runs services correctly and I can connect to PGAdmin without problems.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Every computer is its own localhost, so saying "from localhost" doesn't tell us anything.  Where is your python script running?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, I'm running the code on my own laptop to test, it's a Windows 11, I'm using Docker Desktop.

Comment: So your own laptop here is also the docker host?  This works for me on Windows 11 (but not on Linux, because there the host can't refer to itself as "host.docker.internal", only containers can do that).  It looks like you have a different database already running or mapped from the docker host, and are trying to connect to that one.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test my script on my own computer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after a lot of searching, without finding a solution. By myself, I discovered the problem.
That would be another program using the same port. And that's why it created conflict.
Maybe it's your problem.
If you have it on Windows, run the following commands "CMD ADMINISTRATOR".
Lists the processes that are using port 5432.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :5432
```

The last of the result of this command value is the process ID.

Now finish all the processes. And then start the container again. And it will be working.

```
taskkill /F /PID idprocess
```

Answer (score 0):

this is docker will be access by localhost as host, not `host.docker.internal`

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="project1",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    port=5432
)
```

In future when you try to host container for your script in same docker-compose file then host will be `postgres`

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="postgres",
    database="project1",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    port=5432
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer. I understand I would can set the app in docker file, but in this case I want to access from localhost, I think it's possible. BTW: I tried to set ¨localhost¨ and the error keeping. You can see the error on my question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me your setup so that I can check? Also setup your service in docker